# Typescript: literal type with restrictions

Tags: typescript, types

I have come across the following situation a few times already and have never really found an optimal solution yet. The problem is I want to construct an object with certain restrictions, but also keep the literal type info. The idea is to create a simple object with string keys and restrict the value type.

## Literal type

```js
const pets = {
  dog: {
    sound: "Bark",
    name: "Canis familiaris"
  },
  cat: {
    sound: "Meow",
    name: "Felis catus"
  }
} as const;
```

This preserves all literal information, so you can get a union type of the keys or sounds, e.g.

```js
type PetKey = keyof typeof pets; // 'cat' | 'dog'
type PetSound = typeof pets[PetKey]['sound']; // 'Bark' | 'Meow'
```

However it does not enforce any type in the declaration itself - I would like to enforce that sound and name are strings. You could use some sort of assertion like this:

```js
type Pet = {
  sound: string,
  name: string
}

pets as Record<string, Pet>;
```

Now you'll get a Typescript error if a pet has the wrong type; however the error will be at the line of the assertion, and there's no autocomplete when editing `pets`.

## Record type

```js
type Pet = {
  sound: string,
  name: string
}

const pets: Record<string, Pet> = {
  dog: {
    sound: "Bark",
    name: "Canis familiaris"
  },
  cat: {
    sound: "Meow",
    name: "Felis catus"
  }
}
```

This gives you type checking in place and autocomplete, but loss of literal type information, so now:

```js
type PetKey = keyof typeof pets; // string
type PetSound = typeof pets[PetKey]['sound']; // string
```

## Function helper

This is perhaps the best I was able to find/come up with:

```js
type Pet = {
  sound: string,
  name: string
}

export const assertPets = <T>(_pets: {
    [K in keyof T]: Pet;
}) => _pets;

const pets = assertPets({
  dog: {
    sound: "Bark",
    name: "Canis familiaris"
  },
  cat: {
    sound: "Meow",
    name: "Felis catus"
  }
});

type PetKey = keyof typeof pets; // 'dog' | 'cat'
type PetSound = typeof pets[PetKey]['sound']; // string
```

You'll get autocomplete and type-checking in place. The keys are reserved, but there is still some loss of information, so `PetSound` is still just `string`.
It also feel a bit dirty, because it adds an actual runtime function call.

## Ideal solution

This is where you come in, is there a way to get the best of both worlds? So restricting the type while also preserving the fully literal type?

Comment: As soon as you add a type to your `pets` you will lose the literal type. `However it does not enforce any type in the declaration itself ` That is true, because you're the one who writes the literal type. If you type it, it's not a literal type anymore.

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRGv7N) works for you